# Искать элементы на другой странице с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

Есть сайт на WP. На странице пользователя я подсчитываю количество div отзывов с помощью JS и вывожу это количество на этой же странице в кнопке.

Код JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
const count = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-column.elementor-col-33.elementor-top-column.elementor-element.elementor-element-7992f17.exad-glass-effect-no.exad-sticky-section-no').length;

const countBlockEmelent = document.querySelector('#res');
countBlockEmelent.textContent = count; 
    
</script>
```

Код кнопки:

```
Отзывы: <span id="res" ></span>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне количество отзывов пользователя выводить на другой странице?

Comment: Передавать get параметром или сохранять в localStorage

Comment: А в БД это не сохраняется? Имею ввиду отзывы.

Comment: @XelaNimed, они там хранятся в хаотичном порядке, т.к. сам WordPress их создаёт, поэтому приходится использовать костыли.

Comment: @SwaD, я так понимаю мне способ localStorage не подойдёт, т.к. отзывы могут добавляться.

Comment: [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Предлагаю прекратить извращаться и  считать не дивы, а реальные сущности. Т.е. из БД. Ида. "отзывов" в ВП нет.

Comment: "... они там хранятся в хаотичном порядке". Мы сейчас про БД говорим? Создайте запрос, который возвращает данные в нужном вам виде. Как вариант, посмотрите в логах какие запросы выполняет БД.